# No se muestra mi vista al cambiar de url

Tags: django, python3.6

Estoy aprendiendo Python, en espacia el Framework de Django.
Apenas estoy viendo el tema de las rutas y mostrar diferente contenido dependiendo la ruta.

Esta es la estructura del proyecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> views.py del directorio libreria

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.

def inicio(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h1>Bienvenido al curso</h1>")

def nosotros(request):
    return render(request, 'paginas/nosotros.html')
```

> urls.py del directorio libreria

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url('', views.inicio, name='inicio'),
    url('nosotros', views.nosotros, name='nosotros'),
]
```

> nosotros.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>nosotros</title>
</head>
<body>
    Seccion de nosotrossssssssssssss
</body>
</html>
```

> urls.py del directorio CRUDDjango

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url('', include('libreria.urls')),
]
```

El problema que estoy presentando es que cuando acceso a la ruta de http://localhost:8000/nosotros me manda la vista de inicio y no la de nosotros.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Saben que estoy haciendo mal?

Espero que me puedan apoyar.

Saludos y bonito jueves.

Answer (score -2):

Hola te paso el código corregido en mi GitHub, observa la estructura que tengo

`https://github.com/FranckyCastell/CRUDDjango`

Comment: Por favor, la respuesta tiene que ser completa y estar en la pagina.